# adding numbers from array?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, split, numbers

i have:

```
var str="100px";
var number = str.split("px");
number = number[0];

var km = "100px";
var numberk = km.split("px");
numberk = numberk[0];

var gim = numberk+100;
var kim = number+100;
var fim = number+numberk;
document.write(gim+'<br>'+kim+'<br>'+jim+'<br>');
```

i would be thankfull  if someone could me answere why the result are added like string rather than nummerical number in javascript i have used the `isNaN();` function which shows this as a legal number. So how can this problem be solved.

thanks.

Comment: I seem to remember reading that jQuery can be used to add numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function in order to convert the string returned when spliting into integer:

```
number = parseInt(number[0], 10);
numberk = parseInt(numberk[0], 10);
```

Now the 2 variables are integers and you could perform integer operations on them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put parseInt() around each number before you use it.  In fact, you could do this without removing the "px".

```
 gim = parseInt(km) + 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

simplest way to do this, you don't need to use `split`.

```
var str="150px";
var str1 = (parseInt(str)+100)+"px";
alert(str1);
```

OUTPUT:

```
200px
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Kk3HK/1/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the numbers in `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

use `parseInt()`

```
var number = parseInt(str, 10);
var numberk = parseInt(km, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseInt` to convert the string to a number.

```
var str = "100px";
var number = parseInt(str, 10);
```

`parseInt` stops when it finds the first non-number character, so you don't even need to remove the `"px"`.